# Долго загружается приложение

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Есть файл, из которого приложение читает много данных. Как ускорить этот процесс?

```
String get_words_from_file(){
    String text = "words";
    byte[] buffer = null;
    InputStream is;
    try {
        is = getAssets().open(text);
        int size = is.available();
        buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String str_data = new String(buffer);
    return str_data;
}
```

Comment: Логичным решением видится - не читать при загрузке, а читать во время работы(показа прелоадера).

Comment: И использовать BufferedReader

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков а можете подсказать, как мне его использовать?

Comment: Совет был не моим, но например так: https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/593-bufferedreader-i-bufferedwritter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте BufferedReader. Он гораздо быстрее сырого InputStream. И лучше бы это делать не из UI потока

```
String get_words_from_file() {
    String text = "words";
    // try-with-resources, автоматически закрывает поток
    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(text)))) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //обработать ошибку
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Только приложение всё равно запускается 5с

Comment: Нужно как-то читать файл, не мешая работе

Comment: @КубаркоДмитрий поэтому делайте это в другом потоке

Comment: Да, всё заработало, спасибо!